# How to proxy (almost) all requests through WireMock?

Tags: java, integration-testing, wiremock

I have a following problem: There's a service I'm mocking (for integration tests) using a docker container I run on a specific port. Because the mock service has not been updated (I don't own the code) a few endpoints that exist in the real service are not supported there.

I'm considering forking the repository and adding them myself, but other solution I'm trying is proxying all the requests via a WireMock server and stubbing only the missing endpoints. Is there a simple way to achieve this? It looks like I'd need to proxy every rest method separately, like this:

```
    WireMockServer wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(8080);
    wireMockServer.start();

    // Proxy to the standalone mock server:
    // GET
    wireMockServer.stubFor(get(anyUrl())
        .atPriority(10)
        .willReturn(aResponse().proxiedFrom("http://localhost:8081/the-standalone-service")));

    // POST
    wireMockServer.stubFor(get(anyUrl())
        .atPriority(10)
        .willReturn(aResponse().proxiedFrom("http://localhost:8081/the-standalone-service")));

    // PUT
    wireMockServer.stubFor(put(anyUrl())
        .atPriority(10)
        .willReturn(aResponse().proxiedFrom("http://localhost:8081/the-standalone-service")));

    ...


    // Overwrite only selected endpoints: 
    wireMockServer.stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/the-service/users/"))
        .atPriority(1)
        .willReturn(aResponse()
            .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .withBody("...")));

    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

It took me less time to find an answer than writing the question, there's a `WireMock.any()` method matching all request methods, so this should suffice:

```
// Proxy to the standalone mock server:
wireMockServer.stubFor(WireMock.any(anyUrl())
        .atPriority(10)
        .willReturn(aResponse().proxiedFrom("http://localhost:8081/the-standalone-service")));
```

I'll confirm if it works later today.

Comment: What is the equivalent of `any` in json mapping file?